# Spring & JUnit | How to disable spring test context caching for a specific test class?

Tags: java, spring, caching

My code has many integration tests classes - `ServiceTest1`, `ServiceTest2` ... , `ServiceTestN`.
All tests are executed with spring using the same test context (`MyAppContext.xml`).

As shown in the snippet below, `ServiceTest1` test context requires one of its beans to be overridden, and that change is relevant **ONLY** for `ServiceTest1`.

When executed, `ServiceTest1` works as expected. However, when executing the other tests (e.g. `ServiceTest2` in the snippet) it fails with spring initialization errors, since spring is caching `MyAppContext.xml` test context, and  `ServiceTest1` test context manipulation is conflicting with the other tests.

I'm looking for a way to avoid caching of `ServiceTest1` test context (such as making its caching key unique, based on @ContextConfiguration).
Note that fully disabling caching is not a wanted solution.

Any ideas?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ServiceTest1 {

    // some tests ...

    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({"classpath*:MyAppContext.xml"})
    static class Context {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        ServiceOne serviceOne() {
            // instantiate something ...
        }
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:MyAppContext.xml"})
public class ServiceTest2 {

    // some tests ...

}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Spring initialization errors are:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security]
>
> Offending resource: URL [file:/path/to/MyAppContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Duplicate  detected.
>
> Offending resource: class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]

Answer (score 5):

Use the `@DirtiesContext` annotation, add this at the class level.

It will then refresh the spring application context after the test class has executed.

Documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to do the work. It's clear that `ServiceTest1` is the problem, but I'm not sure where is the conflict. Even when I execute `ServiceTest2` alone it fails.

Comment: if ServiceTest2 doesn't work on its own then changing ServiceTest1 Wont fix the problem. You need to post more of ServiceTest2 plus the spring xml file

Comment: when I remove the specific Context configuration from `ServiceTest1` than everything works fine.

Comment: Hmm ok, you must not be executing Service2 alone properly then. Will still need to see more of the code/config